# How to update the icon and label when the step get completed in material ui core Stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uistepper

```
    import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  actionsContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  resetContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return `For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
              you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
              and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.`;
    case 1:
      return 'An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords.';
    case 2:
      return `Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
              and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
              If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
              they're running and how to resolve approval issues.`;
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

export default function VerticalLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
            <StepContent>
              <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
              <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    disabled={activeStep === 0}
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </StepContent>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      {activeStep === steps.length && (
        <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
          <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Paper>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using material UI core in my code to implement stepper
I want to update the step label and icon whenever the step is completed.
Whenever first step got completed it should show the different icon and label
I am using material UI core in my code to implement stepper
I want to update the step label and icon whenever the step is completed.
Whenever first step got completed it should show the different icon and label

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `StepIconComponent` to the `<StepLabel>`. This is passed whether the step was completed.

```
const LabelIcon = (props) => {
 const { active, completed, className } = props;

 if(completed) {
   return // your completed icon here. Remember to pass `className` to it.
 }

 return // your non-completed icon here. Remember to pass `className` to it.
}
```

You also need to pass a `completed` prop to each step which depends on when you consider it completed in your case. A simple way might be to check if the active step is more than the current one you are rendering. You can also use this logic to switch the label.

```
  import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  actionsContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  resetContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return `For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
              you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
              and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.`;
    case 1:
      return 'An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords.';
    case 2:
      return `Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
              and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
              If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
              they're running and how to resolve approval issues.`;
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

export default function VerticalLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };




  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
        {steps.map((label, index) => { 
          const completed = activeStep > index

          return (
          <Step completed={completed} key={label}>
            <StepLabel StepIconComponent={LabelIcon}>{completed ? 'YOUR CUSTOM COMPLETED LABEL' : label}</StepLabel>
            <StepContent>
              <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
              <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    disabled={activeStep === 0}
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </StepContent>
          </Step>
        ))}}
      </Stepper>
      {activeStep === steps.length && (
        <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
          <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Paper>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have used the same logic and able to change the icon but still not able to change each step label content when its done. Could you please help

Comment: Did you change to `{completed ? 'YOUR CUSTOM COMPLETED LABEL' : label}` as above?

Comment: <StepLabel StepIconComponent={QontoStepIcon}  classes={{ label: lableClasses.label, completed: lableClasses.labelCompleted, active: lableClasses.labelActive }}>{label}</StepLabel>                                                              
 I have used this to change the icon and label font using style         
But not sure How to change the label content which I am getting from getStep const

Comment: Actually for each step I need to change different  label content for example if first step label is "Starting"  after completion I want to show "Started" for each step its different

Comment: {completed? {getStepLabel(props)} : {label}} Trying to implement this but this is changing all the steps text

Comment: Where do you set `completed`? Make sure this is inside the loop as in my example

Comment: I thinky you want this `completed ? label : 'Starting'`